# How can I audit which part of my app is slow?

Tags: next.js, amazon-rds, prisma, vercel

When I run my app locally, it's nice and fast, however, when I deploy to Vercel, things get very very slow. My app is a NextJS app, using Prisma as the db client. The database is an Amazon RDS Postgres instance. I'm pre-launch so there's no real traffic, so I don't think there are issues with connections or that I need a pgbouncer setup... though I don't really know how to audit that either.

Any tips I'd love to hear em!

Comment: I had faced a similar issue when I deployed an application which was working fast on my local machine but became slow once it was deployed to Vercel.

It turned out that the data fetching on the server-side using getServerSideProps was taking too much time. To resolve that issue, I tried to lazy load some data-heavy components on the client-side using next/dynamic.

You can also try out a similar approach to debug. Load only the components which doesn't need to fetch a lot of data on the server-side. In this way, you can **debug** your application.

Comment: Make sure that RDS is in the same region as your Vercel app is in to reduce latency. Also use the latest version of Prisma as `nApi` was made the default and that should make DB requests faster.

Answer (score 0):

Might be worthwhile to use the browser Dev Tools, specifically the Network and Performance tabs, to see if you can find what is slowing you down.

You could also check out using the React Dev Tools and look at the Profiler tool there, but that has to be run locally, which may not be as useful, since you say the app runs fast locally